# Negative sentence of "It seems that~"

Tags: grammar

"It doesn't seem that she knows what it means."

I know the sentence above is correct.
But I wonder if the following sentence is grammatically right, too.

"It seems that she doesn't know what it means."

Is it okay to use "It seems that + negative form" 
in written English??

Comment: Both are grammatical, but they mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

In the first

"It doesn't seem that she knows what it means."

the *doesn't* applies to the seeming. She may well know what it means but it does not look that way to the writer.

In the second;

"It seems that she doesn't know what it means."

The *doesn't* applies to her understanding. This is generally what is meant by the use of *seem to* and as such using it in the first way will most often be understood to mean the same as the second way.

Is it okay to use "It seems that + negative form" in written English??

Yes, I think this is the more common use but both will pass the test of understanding.